# SAS Enterprise guide and conditional Macro Values

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I have a simple macro that checks for the existance of a Dataset (DATA01):

```
%GLOBAL base_exists;
%MACRO does_base_exist();
  %IF %SYSFUNC(exist(DATA_01)) %THEN
    %LET base_exists= 1;
  %ELSE %LET base_exists= 0;

%MEND;

%does_base_exist();

%PUT Base exist check is &base_exists
```

The code above is indicated in a Program that is executed before my main Process. The outpu message reads:

```
"Base exist check is 1"
```

I have place a confition on my main process to only run when &base_exists is equal to 1 (Which it is). For some reason my main process keeps on failing stating that &base_exists does not exist.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I am new to EG and more used to working in BASE SAS.

**UPDATE:**
I have appended a 's' to my errro &base_exists, for clarity sake.

Comment: are you missing "s" in "base_exist's'"?

Comment: 'failing stating that &base_exist does not exist' -- the macro is `&base_exists` -- with the S at the end.  Make sure you have the name correct.

Comment: is it just your post that is missing a semi-colon after the %Put statement? or is that in your code also?

Comment: Could you post a screen print of the condition dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify this even further if you like. A macro is not even necessary.  All you need is this line in open code:

```
%let base_exists = %sysfunc(exist(DATA_01));
```

The function will return a value or `0` or `1` so the `if` statement is not even necessary.  Because you don't need the macro, you also won't need the `%global` statement as any macro defined in open code will be global automatically.

Comment: This is an amazing solution to keep my code clean and concise! Thanks @Robert

Comment: Glad it helped.  Another thing you may find useful is to know that when you check this value later on you can simply do so like this:  `if &base_exists then do; *some code; end;`.  There's no need to explicitly check if the value is equal to 1 in the `if` statement.  This is because a value of zero is equal to false, and any non-zero value (positive or negative) will be equal to true.  This is true for a lot of programming environments.  It means you can keep your code self-documenting if you use well named variables.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix it after various attempts. More experience EG users might see this as trivial, but I'll post it anyway, for beginners such as myself.

I had the macro definitions as part of an AutoExec. I moved it into my process flow and connected it to the Process that uses the macro as a conditional variable. It also needs to be set as %GLOBAL in order to use it outside of the scope of a specific program.

Seems to be happy now.